# Google Cloud Messaging Using Computer

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm not sure if this is in the wrong StackExchange, so if it is, please let me know.

I'm making an Android app that I'd like to use GCM for. Unfortunately, I don't have a server available for me to run this off of. The best I have is a GoDaddy hosted webserver. So, since I figured running GCM off of my webserver wouldn't work, I need to find some other way. Thus, my question: Is it possible to use a local computer with GCM instead of a server? This way, I can use my laptop instead of a server.

Also, if you know of someway to make the GoDaddy hosting work with GCM that would be even better. The GoDaddy is a shared webhosting account, not a VPS or a dedicated sever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can send a GCM message from your local computer to your Android device via GCM server. All you need is to be connected to the internet, and send an HTTP request to the GCM HTTP endpoint.

However, in order to send such a message, you need to know the Registration ID of the device that should get the message. The application of the device gets this ID when it registers to GCM. Usually, once the app receives this ID, it passes it to your server. If you use your local computer as a server, you will find it difficult to send the registration ID from your app to it (though you might be able to do it if you are running a local web-server on your local computer, and the Android device and your computer are connected to the internet by the same network).

Of course, you can always copy the registration ID manually and paste it into your code that sends the GCM messages.

Comment: If all it requires is a simple HTTP request, then would I be able to accomplish that through PHP? If so, then would that allow me to use my GoDaddy shared webhosting to do this without having to copy/paste the Registration ID?

Comment: Also, I noticed that on the GCM website, it said that an HTTP request would only allow downstream and that I need to use XMPP to do up/downstream. Is this an easy task to do if I were to use PHP?

Comment: @Globmont I don't know what GoDaddy allows or doesn't allow. Yes, you can accomplish the HTTP request through PHP. You'll also need your server to implement a service that accepts registration IDs from your app, and stores them in a DB. Yes, HTTP is only for downstream. XMPP is much more complex to implement. I never tried XMPP myself, so I can't say much about it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think what I'll do is use GCM to send data from my server to the Android device, and then make a POST request from the Android device back to my server to send back data. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, as a matter of fact im using [this](https://gcm.codeplex.com/) 
gcm sender application to test my gcm-client in phone. I wrote an abstraction of gcm-client for simpleton like me [here](https://github.com/montecillodavid/gcm-client-library)

hope it helps :).

Comment: Oooh! Thank you so much! Those both look really useful. I'll definitely be looking closer at them!